# How to get a certain field of an embedded MongoDB document knowing its ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two collections in MongoDB database, Post and User. Each post contains the creator's ObjectId. When fetching all posts from the database, I want to add the name information, which is a field of User/creator. I tried to access the name field by post.creator.name, but it is not working.

```js
const postSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    category: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    imageUrl: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    creator: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  isExpert: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
  },
  posts: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Post",
    },
  ],
});
```

```js
exports.getPosts = (req, res, next) => {
  Post.find({}).then((posts) => {
    const postsWithAuthorName = posts.map(post => {
      return {
        ...post,
        name: post.creator.name
      }
    })
    res.status(200).json({
      posts: postsWithAuthorName,
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: `post.creator` is of type `ObjectId` so you can't just get name. You can for e.g. query users to get this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Post.find({}).populate('creator', 'name')
```

See [populate doc](https://populate) for reference.

When you query posts, creator is just an `ObjectId`, so you can't just call `.name` on it. To make it work you need to [lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) this data by using e.g. `populate`.